# Why is template<class InputIt> deque::deque(InputIt first, InputIt last, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() ) suboptimal?

Tags: c++, stl, deque

There is a deque constructor that accepts pair of iterators. As I can see, in both GCC libstdc++ and llvm libc++ when the iterators are from a list, the list is scanned two times, 1st during distance() calculation, and then when the list elements are copied.

Is something fundamental in C++ prevents this from be optimized? Or is this a shortcoming of the implementations?

```cpp
std::list<int> v = { 4, 3, 2, 1 };
std::deque<int> d(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Comment: It's not suboptimal: if you notice, there's also a constructor that takes an input iterator where the range is iterated over only once. The distance calculation allows the container to perform only a single allocation, while keeping the same time complexity. For random-access iterators, that length calculation is constant time. For forward and bidirectional iterators, the length calculation has a time complexity of `O(n)` with a small coefficient. It's actually much faster than the alternative.

Comment: Actually it's only 2x (constant factor) slower, not very significant.

Comment: @alexander ,

_It's actually much faster than the alternative._

Could you please share the details? On my machine, for list<int> with 100,000,000 elements, alternative with push_back is ~1.86 times faster, if we use jemalloc. The picture is different for glibc malloc, so another possibility is that standard library developers are oriented toward allocators from 80s. What a pity!

Comment: @AlexandrKonovalov You're not thinking about this properly. For any allocator, for any circumstances, the average, worst-case of the size-then-copy is better than the dynamically-elongation worst-case. If you get very lucky, and use primitive types with trivial copy or move constructors, and every reallocation can be done in-place, you can get equal time complexity with the dynamic elongation approach to the size-then-copy approach. This is much better summed up in an answer, but your trivial benchmark is likely misleading, at best.